# code triggers or hook in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, triggers, hook

I was thinking about a trigger functions. I wounder if they exist in ASP.net or not. I have looked up for it but i could not find anything relating to it.

what i mean by trigger functions is you define a trigger class where you identify all trigger function in your code.

trigger class will contain a list of trigger function as the following:

TRIGGER(METHOD_A_THE_TRIGGER, METHOD_B)

so now any time Method A execute automatically Method B will execute as will without the need for me to modify Method A at all.

Why I am asking about this.

for example a developer wrote a program for room reservation that some features are missing.
i need to add these feature but i dont want to modify the code in case the developer updated his code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to 'raise an event' (what you're calling 'trigger' -- which probably won't turn up anything in Google for asp.net).

Quick ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkzf914z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: and because i don't want to modify the api code, so i will write something like this, methodtrigger(userlogin, recordUserLoginTrails) and this method will be added in a class i created my self or it

Comment: might be defined in the global and it will call the function recordUserLoginTrails everytime userlogin function get executed and it will pass the parameters of userlogin and its return value as well.